# How can I implement a preloader animation into my website?

Tags: html, css

How can I implement a pre shown web page into my size which displays for a few seconds when the user first clicks on the URL of my website? For example, on [this](https://caferati.me) website the developer has put a logo with a transition of some sort and then his website loads. I'm trying to implement this into my website. However, I was wondering if anyone new the technical name for this so I can read up on how to do it and if anyone could possibly show me how to do it and get me going?

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/liamdocherty1/pen/awwBQX) for my website. I linked this incase you need to add some code in order for the webpage to display there at the start for around 3 seconds.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/liamdocherty1/pen/jwwwVK) I want to be displayed for the 3 seconds at the start.

Below is the HTML/CSS of the codepen I'm trying to display for 3 seconds before the website loads.

```css
body{
 background:#333;
 background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 120, center center, 900, from(#111), to(#111));
 background:-moz-radial-gradient(circle, #111, #111);

}
.loader{
 margin:200px auto;
}
h1{
 font-family: 'Actor', sans-serif;
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:16px;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-weight:200;
 text-align:center;
}
.loader span{
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 border-radius:50%;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-10px;
 -webkit-animation:3s infinite linear;
 -moz-animation:3s infinite linear;
 -o-animation:3s infinite linear;
 
}


.loader span:nth-child(2){
 background:blye;
 -webkit-animation:kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
 -moz-animation:kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
 -o-animation:kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
 
}
.loader span:nth-child(3){
 background:red;
 z-index:100;
}
.loader span:nth-child(4){
 background:red;
 -webkit-animation:kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
 -moz-animation:kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
 -o-animation:kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes kanan {
    0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
    }
   
 50%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
 
 100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
 z-index:200;
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes kanan {
    0% {-moz-transform:translateX(20px);
    }
   
 50%{-moz-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
 
 100%{-moz-transform:translateX(20px);
 z-index:200;
 }
}
@-o-keyframes kanan {
    0% {-o-transform:translateX(20px);
    }
   
 50%{-o-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
 
 100%{-o-transform:translateX(20px);
 z-index:200;
 }
}




@-webkit-keyframes kiri {
     0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
 z-index:200;
    }
 50%{-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
 }
 100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes kiri {
     0% {-moz-transform:translateX(-20px);
 z-index:200;
    }
 50%{-moz-transform:translateX(20px);
 }
 100%{-moz-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
}
@-o-keyframes kiri {
     0% {-o-transform:translateX(-20px);
 z-index:200;
    }
 50%{-o-transform:translateX(20px);
 }
 100%{-o-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div class="loader">
    <h1>LIAM DOCHERTY'S PORTFOLIO IS</h1>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  <br>
  <h1>LOADING</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<tag onload="myFunction()">` where the function is to hide the pre-loader

Comment: Thanks for the comment, do you know what this is called and do you know any helpful URL's?

Comment: [Onload Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp). I am sure there are other more efficient ways of doing this, but here's how I would do it.  1- Wrap the content you want to show in a div 2- Make the `div` the size of the screen and give it a + `z-index` value. 3- set its display to show up by default. 4- write a small script that changes that div's display to none. 5- use `onload` to trigger the script once the content of your porfolio is loaded.

Comment: So you are looking for a preloader animation?

Comment: @Pons Purushothaman I already have a preorder animation, I'm looking for help on implementing the preloaded animation into my site.

Comment: @I haz kode I will look into this now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `splash` screen in case of `android`, you can use the same term for web or you can call it `loading` screen.
The trick behind implementing it is usually to show the splash screen until the `webapp` is loaded.

Lets say for your code-

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="splash">
        <h1>LIAM DOCHERTY'S PORTFOLIO IS</h1>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <br>
        <h1>LOADING</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS

```
body{
    background:#333;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 120, center center, 900, from(#111), to(#111));
    background:-moz-radial-gradient(circle, #111, #111);

}
#app {
    display: none;
}
.splash{
    margin:200px auto;
}
h1{
    font-family: 'Actor', sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:16px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-weight:200;
    text-align:center;
}
.splash span{
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-10px;
    -webkit-animation:3s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation:3s infinite linear;
    -o-animation:3s infinite linear;

}


.splash span:nth-child(2){
    background:blue;
    -webkit-animation:kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation:kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation:kiri 1.2s infinite linear;

}
.splash span:nth-child(3){
    background:red;
    z-index:100;
}
.splash span:nth-child(4){
    background:red;
    -webkit-animation:kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation:kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation:kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes kanan {
    0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
    }

    50%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
    }

    100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
    z-index:200;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes kanan {
    0% {-moz-transform:translateX(20px);
    }

    50%{-moz-transform:translateX(-20px);
    }

    100%{-moz-transform:translateX(20px);
    z-index:200;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes kanan {
    0% {-o-transform:translateX(20px);
    }

    50%{-o-transform:translateX(-20px);
    }

    100%{-o-transform:translateX(20px);
    z-index:200;
    }
}




@-webkit-keyframes kiri {
     0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
    z-index:200;
    }
    50%{-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
    }
    100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes kiri {
     0% {-moz-transform:translateX(-20px);
    z-index:200;
    }
    50%{-moz-transform:translateX(20px);
    }
    100%{-moz-transform:translateX(-20px);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes kiri {
     0% {-o-transform:translateX(-20px);
    z-index:200;
    }
    50%{-o-transform:translateX(20px);
    }
    100%{-o-transform:translateX(-20px);
    }
}
```

You can either use it in two ways now-

1. You can either make it dependent on your scripts, that until the `js` files are loaded, splash screen will display.
2. Or you can simply display the splash screen for `3 seconds` and continue with your `webapp`.

To do the first, simply add the following script tag after all the other `js` files script tags( or simple after `body` tag. HTML won't run this script tag until it has fetched the `js` files added before it.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('app').style['display'] = 'block';
    document.getElementById('splash').style['display'] = 'none';
</script>
```

To do the second, add a `settimeout()` method to your script tag and place it at the head of your `HTML`.

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        document.getElementById('app').style['display'] = 'block';
        document.getElementById('splash').style['display'] = 'none';
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks so much. In order to change the amount of time it takes to switch to the site would I change the "3000" in the JS? In addition, when I add the JS to the code when the website loads its a spit view of the pre loading page and the website loading page?

Comment: Yes, `3000` is milliseconds. And what i meant by `js` was, for when you are using dynamic html rendering rather than static html, you will probably have a big `bundle.js` such as in languages `reactjs` and `angularjs`. In that case you will want to display this splash screen until your `js` is fetched from network, which will further generate your dynamic HTML view. And NO the website won't load in split view, the `display: none` property completely removes the `splash` div, whereas `display: block` shows the hidden `app` div.

Comment: I was researching for a similar solution. The following video on youtube https://youtu.be/xuA83OYTE7I includes very specific and simple step-by-step instructions to follow. The result is amazing. It's worth a try. For those interested in trying to Create your own Page Pre-Loader (HTML, CSS & JS) (No-jQuery Needed).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a preloader, use a structure like this

```
<div id="preloader" style="display:block">preloader here</div>
<div id="webpage" style="display:none">site content</div>
```

then using script, on page load, hide "#preloader" and show "#webpage" like below

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#preloader").hide();
  $("#webpage"").show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
// <div class="splash"> change to  <div id="splash">
    <div id="splash">
        <h1>LIAM DOCHERTY'S PORTFOLIO IS</h1>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <br>
        <h1>LOADING</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).